# Modifying dataframe subset isn't changing source

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to normalize subsets of data from a dataframe in python. As I understand, setting one df equal to another only references and doesn't copy - such that changing the new df also changes the old. When I try to leverage this, though, the changes I'm making aren't showing up in the original df.

```
temp = df.loc[(df['sample']==s) & (df['pixel']==p),['pce']]
nval=temp.iloc[0]['pce']
temp['pce']=temp['pce']/nval
```

I expected that modification of temp would also modify df, but this doesn't seem to be the case. The normalization is only happening in temp. What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning one df to another only copies the reference to the dataframe object, so this assumption is correct. However, slicing the original dataframe cannot copy the reference, it creates a new object which is different to the original dataframe, it is a subset of it. The new object does not contain all of the original dataframes' data. If you want to modify subset of the original dataframe, assign the newly created data back to where you got them from.

```
temp = df.loc[(df['sample']==s) & (df['pixel']==p),['pce']]
nval=temp.iloc[0]['pce']
temp['pce']=temp['pce']/nval
df.loc[temp.index, 'pce'] = temp['pce']
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to be clear, though, when I write back to the original, it will only overwrite the subset I modified?

Comment: yes if you tried to overwrite more/less data that would naturally rise an error, if your problem is  solved now, consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer that helped you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (hopefully I'm not missing something either), this is the normal behavior.
In order to change the values in `df`, try using the indices of the sliced DataFrame instead:

```
df.loc[temp.index, 'pce'] = df.loc[temp.index, 'pce'] / nval
```